# Connect to Heroku Postgres through external application

Tags: heroku, pgadmin, navicat

I have a Heroku Ruby app, and I want to access the DB through Navicat, or pgAdmin, or similar. However, the thing that Heroku gives me as a DB URL doesn't seem to be a valid URL.

Heroku tells me to use: `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a your-app` However, that gives me something of the form

```
postgres://HUGE:STRINGOF@GIBERISH.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/MORECHARACTERS
```

which doesn't look like a valid URL to me, and both Navicat and pgAdmin fail to connect.

How can I use this value to connect to my database?

Answer (score 1):

That "huge string of gibberish" is [a completely valid URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax).

`postgres` is the scheme, just like `https` is a scheme.

What you have marked as `HUGE` is your username and what you have marked as `STRINGOF` is your password. Together, they make up the `userinfo` subcomponent.

`GIBERISH` just is part of the domain, `5432` is the port, and `MORECHARACTERS` is the name of the database.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know what MORE and MORECHARACTERS were... However, it still doesn't work. maybe without the user info? hmm

Comment: Concretely, try connecting to `GIBERISH.compute-1.amazonaws.com` on port `5432` using `HUGE` as your username, `STRINGOF` as your password, and select the database `MORECHARACTERS`. You probably don't need to explicitly include `postgres://` anywhere, but you may have to select the right driver depending on your client.

Comment: I also recommend enabling SSL. I can't remember if Heroku Postgres enforces that, but if it does that might be why you're not able to connect.

Comment: interesting. Ok, so now it complains about the password. I've tried what **I** think my password/user name is, and what you suggested, and both failed. I'll put the whole message in the post.

Comment: GRR. I'm dyslexic and flipped which part was the user and which was the password! I think it works now! testing!